# extracting a piece of text from HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need to be able to extract snippet one, without capturing snippet two, which is disabled, using a single CSS selector.

```
snippet one
<button data-v-4e0029d1=""><div data-v-4e0029d1="">Small</div></button>

snippet two
<button data-v-4e0029d1=""><div data-v-4e0029d1="">Large</div><div class="disabled" data-v-4e0029d1="">disabled</div></button>
```

I am drawing a blank, I have tried the following:

```
html.css("button > div:first-child:not(:has(button > div + div.disabled))")
```

```
html.css("button > div:not(:has(div.disabled))")
```

```
html.css("button > div:not(.disabled)")
```

```
html.css("button > div[data-v-^]")
```

here is a reproducible example

```
from selectolax.parser import HTMLParser

html = """
<button data-v-4e0029d1=""><div data-v-4e0029d1="">Small</div></button>
<button data-v-4e0029d1=""><div data-v-4e0029d1="">Large</div><div class="disabled" data-v-4e0029d1="">disabled</div></button>

html = HTMLParser(html)
"""
```

Any help would be most appreciated. FYI I used selectolax for parsing however for this example and support I do not mind a bs4 flavour.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<button data-v-4e0029d1=""><div data-v-4e0029d1="">Small</div></button>
<button data-v-4e0029d1=""><div data-v-4e0029d1="">Large</div><div class="disabled" data-v-4e0029d1="">disabled</div></button>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

button = soup.select('button:not(:has(.disabled))')
print(button)
```

Prints:

```
[<button data-v-4e0029d1=""><div data-v-4e0029d1="">Small</div></button>]
```

Comment: thank you for sharing, for some reason, this is not working for me. however this did ```button > div:not(.disabled):not(:has(+ .disabled))```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative check with the data. Used BeautifulSoup here though.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<button data-v-4e0029d1=""><div data-v-4e0029d1="">Small</div></button>
<button data-v-4e0029d1=""><div data-v-4e0029d1="">Large</div><div class="disabled" data-v-4e0029d1="">disabled</div></button>
"""

enabled_buttons = [button for button in BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').find_all('button') if not button.find('div', {'class': 'disabled'})]
print(enabled_buttons)
```

Output:

```
[<button data-v-4e0029d1=""><div data-v-4e0029d1="">Small</div></button>]
```

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, I managed to solve it using:

```
button > div:not(.disabled):not(:has(+ .disabled))
```